# Is there any way to find out duplicates value in mysql while inserting records?

Tags: php, mysql

I read many questions but i didn't found my solution to my question.

My concern:

I am inserting new records in My SQL, using foreach loop in PHP. So, before inserting is there any way to find out, the records i am inserting in my sql is already present or not. If it is present then it should return "ALREADY EXIST".

AS PER MY CODE:

As i am using FOR-EACH LOOP , i want which **qstonesid** is already exist in my sql **tbl_stickering**.
If exist then it should return ECHO "**$qstonesid already exist**" and if **$qstonesid** not exist then call my STORED PROCEDURE **sp_stickering**.

I hope i made my concern clear, and i am totally new to PHP and mySql, any help will be appreciated,

Below, I am sharing my PHP code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

include "config.php";



$stones = $_POST['stones'];
//echo json_encode($stones, true);
$StoneArr = json_decode($stones, true);

$updstmt = '';

  foreach ($StoneArr as $Stone)
  {


    $currentdate=!empty( $Stone['currentdate'] ) ? $Stone['currentdate'] : '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    $qstonesid=$Stone['qstonesid'];

    $clientname = $_REQUEST['clientname'];
    $empid = $_REQUEST['empid'];



     $updstmt .= 'CALL sp_stickering('.'"'.$currentdate.'"'.',
                                          '.'"'.$clientname.'"'.',
                                          '.'"'.$qstonesid.'"'.',
                                          '.'"'.$empid.'"'.'
                                        );';
  }



    //echo $updstmt;
       $res = query($updstmt);


       if (strlen($res) > 0) {
           echo $res;
        } else {
            echo 'Records added successfully...';
            }
```

below is my Stored Procedure I am using,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_stickering`(
 IN `_sdate_stickering` DATETIME,
 IN `_client_name` VARCHAR(100),
 IN `_qstonesid` VARCHAR(100),
 IN `_empid` INT
)
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT qstonesid FROM tbl_stickering WHERE qstonesid = _qstonesid AND client_name = _client_name) THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_stickering SET empid = _empid WHERE qstonesid = _qstonesid AND client_name = _client_name;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_stickering
    (sdate_stickering, client_name, qstonesid, empid)
    VALUES
    (_sdate_stickering, _client_name, _qstonesid, _empid);
END;
END IF;

END
```

Comment: You are wanting to `UPDATE` if it exists or `INSERT` if it does not?

Comment: @fyrye, I want to INSERT qstonesid if it does not present in table and echo qstonesid already present in tbl_stickering'.

Comment: after IF EXISTS , i am updating, which i dont want to do.., I just want to show users which qstonesid is already present in database. and if not present then just insert those qstonesid which is not present.

Comment: but you want to always call the stored procedure `sp_stickering`? I am a bit confused as to your approach on combining all of the procedure calls as it seems a bit redundant.

Comment: @fyrye, i only want to call stored procedure for those qstonesid which is not present in tbl_stickering.

Comment: @fyrye, I updated my SP just for your refrence in where clause for select qstonesid where qstonesid and client_name are there.

Comment: @fyrye, I got this error, Error<br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= "66" 
AND qstonesid IN(WLSD-09603,WLSD-09540)' at line 3<br>1064.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to retrieve a listing of `qstonesid` from the array and check the database prior to calling the procedure.

To get a list of `qstonesid` values from `$StoneArr` you can use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$ids = array_column($StoneArr, 'qstonesid');
```

Next retrieve the listing of those `$ids` that exists in the database and build another listing of those that exist.

I am not sure what database extension you are using, but I presume something like this. See the working example link below for a [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) demonstration with prepared statements.

```
$rs = query('SELECT qstonesid FROM tbl_stickering WHERE qstonesid IN(' . implode(',', $ids) . ')');
$exists = array_column($rs, 'qstonesid');
```

if `qstonesid` is an array of string values, you can wrap each value with quotes by using.

```
'"' . implode('","', $ids) . ') . '"';
```

Lastly in your `foreach` loop use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check in your resulting `$exists` array for the `$Stone['qstonesid']` and use [`continue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) to move on to the next iteration if it is.

### Working Example: https://3v4l.org/eJXu5

```
foreach ($StoneArr as $Stone) {
    if (in_array($Stone['qstonesid'], $exists)) {
        echo $Stone['qstonesid'] . ' Already Exists.';
        continue;
    }

    //...
}
```

### Full Example:

```
  $stones = $_POST['stones'];
  $StoneArr = json_decode($stones, true);

  //retrieve listing of submitted qstonesid values
  $StoneArrIds = array_column($StoneArr, 'qstonesid');

  //retrieve listing of existing qstonesid
  /**
   * modify to suit your database extension
   * !! Subject to SQL Injection !!
   * !! HIGHLY RECOMMEND USING PREPARED STATEMENTS !!
   */
  $rs = query('SELECT qstonesid 
FROM tbl_stickering 
WHERE client_name = "' . $_REQUEST['clientname'] . '" 
AND qstonesid IN("' . implode('","', $StoneArrIds) . '")');
  $exists = array_column($rs, 'qstonesid');

  $updstmt = '';
  foreach ($StoneArr as $Stone) {
    //qstonesid already exists, display a message and skip insertion
    if (in_array($Stone['qstonesid'], $exists)) {
        echo $Stone['qstonesid'] . ' already exist';
        continue;
    }

    $currentdate= !empty($Stone['currentdate'] ) ? $Stone['currentdate'] : '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    $qstonesid = $Stone['qstonesid'];
    $clientname = $_REQUEST['clientname'];
    $empid = $_REQUEST['empid'];
    $updstmt .= 'CALL sp_stickering('.'"'.$currentdate.'"'.',
                                          '.'"'.$clientname.'"'.',
                                          '.'"'.$qstonesid.'"'.',
                                          '.'"'.$empid.'"'.'
    );';
  }

  if ($updstmt) {
      $res = query($updstmt);
      if (strlen($res) > 0) {
          echo $res;
      } else {
          echo 'Records added successfully...';
      }
  }
```

Comment: hello @fyrye, thanks for your help, But i am not able to integrate my code in your code, Will please help me. In this

Comment: @vishu_tech I updated my answer with a full example. Please let me know what part you are specifically having difficulty with.

Comment: hello @fyrye, $rs = query('SELECT qstonesid FROM tbl_stickering WHERE qstonesid IN(' . implode(',', $StoneArrIds) . ')');  alongwith qstonesid, i want client_name also in WHERE clause.

Comment: See i updated my stored procedure , where i guess you'll get my concern from **IF EXISTS**  , thanks

Comment: yes it is echoing but also giving error,                                                   WLSD-09603 already existWLSD-09540 already exist                        
    Error<br>Query was empty<br>1065

Comment: You need to check `$updstmt` is not `empty` before using `$res = query($updstmt);`, updated the answer to include that condition.  There are a lot more control-flow issues with your code that also need to be addressed.

Comment: I want to thank you, coz your solution worked for me. You have lots of patience, and helping nature.

Comment: Please don't suggest code that even you yourself say shouldn't be used. Show an example of prepared statements.

Comment: My point is that your question doesn't have that code. You link to it outside. OP doesn't seem to be using any library. It's just a plain wrapper function.

Comment: @Dharman without knowing what libraries or functions their include file has, it is not possible to ascertain what it returns or which functions to call to provide an equivalent solution. I answered the OPs *specific* question using the code they provided. I directed the user to use prepared statements and provided an example albeit external. Anything beyond that is outside of the scope for StackOverflow and are better reserved topics on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)